# Coq: fixed universe hierarchy w/ explicit universes

Tags: types, coq

I'm looking into the possibility of using [`explicit universes`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual032.html#hevea_default1067) for building a *fixed universe hierarchy* in Coq. The attempt to use constants (2, 3, 4) in building it failed: at the end, all combinations still typecheck (i.e. all declared universes are treated as hierarchically arbitrary):

```
Universe k l m x y z.
Let x := 2.
Definition k := Type@{x}.
Notation y := 3.
Definition l := Type@{y}.
Notation z := 4.
Definition m := Type@{z}.
Print x. (*x = 2: nat*)
Print y. (*Notation y := 3*)
Check l:k:m.
Check m:k:l.
Check k:m:l.
```

Note that `Definition k := Type@{2}` and `Definition k := Type@{x+1}` result in a syntax error. Is it possible to use explicit universes for building a fixed hierarchy and if so, how?

Comment: The exact universe expressions that are allowed are: Set (0), a variable, a variable + 1, and max(). See near the end of https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/core/sorts.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can use the [`Constraint`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual032.html#ConstraintCmd) command:

```
Universes x y z.

Constraint x < y, y < z.

Definition X := Type@{x}.
Definition Y := Type@{y}.
Definition Z := Type@{z}.

Check X:Y.
Check Y:Z.
Check X:Z.
Fail Check Z:Y.
Fail Check Y:X.
Fail Check Z:X.
```

Notice that this approach doesn't really fix universe levels as well.

Comment: Obviously, this is the way it was meant to be done. I suspect it's impossible to fix the levels of declared universe variables

Comment: I think you're right. I haven't looked in the source code, but from the papers I've read I gather that there is no such thing as explicit numbers for universe levels, only constraints between abstract variables. I might be wrong though. If you want to be sure the best place to ask is the Coq Club mailing list.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 4):

The way I've gotten it to work is as follows:

```
Universe X Y Z.
Definition x := Type@{X}.
Definition y := Type@{Y}.
Definition z := Type@{Z}.

(* bogus definition to fix hierarchy *)
Definition dummy:x:y:z := unit.

Check x:y.
(* ok:
   x : y
        : y
*)

Check x:z.
(* also ok (transitivity is still acceptable):
   x : z
        : z
*)

Check z:y.
(* Error:
   The term "z" has type "Type@{Z+1}" while it is expected to have type "y"
   (universe inconsistency: Cannot enforce Z < Y because Y < Z).
*)
```

(But maybe someone more knowledgeable than me will chime in with better ideas? In particular, this approach doesn't allow to declare fixed constants so there may still be arbitrary many levels in between declared levels.)

Answer (score 1):

You can stipulate a fixed universe hierarchy w/ an axiom:

```
Universe X Y Z.
Notation X := Type@{X}.
Notation Y := Type@{Y}.
Definition Z := Type@{Z}.
Axiom fuh: (fun (x:Type) => x)(X:Y:Z).
Check X:Y.
Check Y:Z.
Check X:Z.
Fail Check Z:Y.
Fail Check Y:X.
Fail Check Z:X.
```

The particular problem posed by nobody remains an open challenge